# Is bidimensional comparison a SCM feature?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, comparison, diff

We have uni- and bi-dimensional diff tools. But we have those two flavors also for VCSes?
Is it correct to say that SVN is unidimensional and modern SCMs are bidimensional?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I find the terms intriguing. Could you explain what you mean by uni-, bi- dimensional?

Comment: What do you mean? Or did you mean "-directional", or "2-way-diff vs. 3-way-diff", or something like that?

Comment: @julkie @KingCrunch No, it's not 2-way-diff. By bidimensional I mean that when a file differs only by few characters inside a line, the patch will not include the whole line content, instead it will contain the bidimensional coordinates of the change and only affected characters. In the unidimensional case the whole line is contained in the patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCMs primarily use what you call unidimensional diffs. Git, for example, can produce word-by-word diffs (with configurable notions of what "words" are), but the focus is on human readability, and it's not the default behavior. In particular, if you want to generate patches to be applied elsewhere, you'll use line-by-line (unidimensional) diffs. As far as I know, this is true of all of the common current SCMs - and some may not even provide the bidimensional (word diff) capability.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about 2/3-way diffs.
This is not the reponsability of the version control system to process diffs, but the (G)UI you use for it.

When a conflict occurs in SVN, you have 3 different files in your working copy : Your original file, the upcomming version and the base common version.

For instance, Subclipse (SVN Frontend for Eclipse) provides a 3-way comparison based on these 3 files, to help you resolve conflicts.

Comment: As I pointed out in a comment to my question, bidimensional comparision is almost unrelated to 2/3-way diffs